# How can I get separate value of the array item in the codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-2

I have a Controller in Codeigniter which has given sample of code

```
$data = array();
if ($query = $this->product_model -> get_individual_records())
{
    $data['records'] = $query;
}
```

here $data store user_id and market_id fetch from the database

what I want to do is I want to store the user_id stored in the $data array to a separate variable like 
$uid = the value that that is stored in the array name $data[]

How can i get separate value of the array item in the codeigniter

Comment: Do you mean you want to access user_id, market_id one by one ? If so you can use foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are getting the records through `results()` method, you can do like 
`$data['uid'] = $query-> uid;`